# How to add a jQuery UI slider behavior on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am wondering how to attach a jQuery UI slider behavior on dom elements that are loaded dynamically in the page.

It means that the element that should behave like a slider may not be in the page when my javascript file is loaded. Then, when added dynamically in the page, I would like the element to behave like a slider.

When I want to add a behavior on an element that is loaded dynamically in the page, so far I was doing like this:

```
    $('body).on('click', '.myclass', function(){....});
    $('body).on('change', '.myclass', function(){....});
```

Would you happen to know how I can do the same for sliders? `$('.myclass').slider(...)` does not create the slider.

Thank you

Comment: make use of `setInterval` and after attaching the `slider` `clear` the interval

Comment: what do you mean by "loaded dynamically" ? if you load it via jquery ajax, you can call the slider method on loaded element when the complete/success callback fires

Comment: I mean I am adding the slider in the page by clicking on a button (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('body').on('slidecreate', '.myclass', function(){....});
```

But you will also need to initialize the event when elements are added to DOM:

```
$('.myclass').slider();
```

Comment: Many thanks, I was not aware the event slidecreate existed, it works as expected now.